# Use transparent stroke color with chartjs pie chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Following the [chart.js docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-chart-options), I try to draw a transparent stroke line in a pie chart:

```
var options = { segmentStrokeColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0)" };
```

or

```
var options = { segmentStrokeColor: "transparent" };
```

But the stroke line is not drawn with these values. Of course it works if I use any other color.

Comment: Can you use your own class names in chart.js?

Comment: @lharby - Do you mean to use an other name for `options` object?

Comment: I was thinking if you can apply your own class name to the element you want, you can then write svg css, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-opacity. Set stroke opacity to 0. But this might not be supported as part of the chart.js options.

Comment: Why not make a jsfiddle? And we can try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The border or segment stroke is drawn **over** the sectors. So if you set the color to transparent, you won't see any gap between the sectors (I assume that is what you are expecting). It'll be almost as if you set storkewidth to 0.

It's pretty obvious if you set the segmentStrokeWidth to a high enough value and set a translucent value i.e. something like

```
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data, {
    segmentStrokeWidth: 20,
    segmentStrokeColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)"
});
```

Contrast this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tabb8gy0/ with this - http://jsfiddle.net/m2k62fgp/